# OpenCV with DirectX sample error

Tags: c++, opencv, directx

I am trying to run an OpenCV with DirectX example: d3dsample.cpp from [[here]](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/directx/d3dsample.hpp). But it crashes on

> initializeContextFromD3D11Device

The error is "Access violation executing ..." (look like it is not possible to initialize the context from D3D to OpenCL. I have no idea to solve with this problem.

I found some possible duplicate at OpenCV question board  [[here]](http://answers.opencv.org/question/68290/directx-interop-in-30-nvidia-card/), but they are no any progress through last year.

If some one success to build this sample code, please give a suggestion. 
PS: I am using OpenCV 3.1 on Visual Studio 2013 (vc120), Nvidia GTX980 graphics card.

Update:
I am trying to debug with both d3d10_interop and d3d11_interop. 
The d3d10_interop gave me a exeption:

> C:\OpenCV\3.1\sources\modules\core\src\directx.cpp:449: error:
>   (-222) OpenCL: Can't create context for DirectX interop in function
>   cv::directx::ocl::initializeContextFromD3D10Device\n" ...} ...}

Comment: It seems that the error is already telling you the location of the problem?

Comment: @legalize umm, yes, but I am not sure how I can solve this problem. It seems like cv::directx::ocl cannot initialize the memory or something like that. If you have some experience, could you please helping me?